# Github API: Fetch issues with exceeds rate limit prematurely

Tags: github, github-api

I am building an app that fetches the [issues and pull requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/) of over 1K github repos, like this.

```
$ curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/issues?state=closed"
```

My problem is that, after the initial 60 iterations I get a rate limit error:

```
{
    "message": "API rate limit exceeded for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting"
}
```

The document says I can make upto 5000 requests using [Authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) Which I registered an oauth for and obtained `Client ID` and `Client Secret` tokens

`https://api.github.com/repos/{repo.name}/issues?client_id=...&client_secret=...`

Still the rate limit shows up only after about 60 requests.

Comment: You will probably have to cache whatever data you have and be a bit more selective about when / how you fetch it. What possible reason could you have to hit this API endpoint for over 1K repositories in a loop like this?

Comment: I have updated the question and added clarity. I am saving the data to database actually if that is what you are referring to "*caching*".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The public GitHub API requests are limited to 60 / hour / ip, like you observed. That's why you need authentication.

There are [multiple ways to get authenticated](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/) when you use the GitHub APIs.

#### [Basic authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication)

Basically, you provide the username and the password.

```
curl -u your-username "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/issues?state=closed"
```

This will prompt you for entering the password.

If you dont want to use the password, you can use a [personal token](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens):

```
curl -u username:token "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/issues?state=closed"
```

### Using personal access tokens

This is my favorite, but make sure you don't share the token code with others. To generate a new token, [open this page](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new), and you will create the token.

Then you can use it like this:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/issues?state=closed&access_token=token"
```

(replace the `token` snippet at the end of the url with your token code)

### OAuth

If you want to implement authentication for other users, you should use OAuth. The [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) are good in this direction.

Comment: The access token should be in a header. `-H "Authorization: token $token"`

Comment: With this I can only access it in terminal. How can I use this as url in retrofit?