# How to check my GitHub current rate limit?

Tags: github, github-api

The GitHub page https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/ shows a rate limit status as example:

**Response**

```
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1372700873
{
  "resources": {
    "core": {
      "limit": 5000,
      "remaining": 4999,
      "reset": 1372700873
    },
    "search": {
      "limit": 30,
      "remaining": 18,
      "reset": 1372697452
    }
  },
  "rate": {
    "limit": 5000,
    "remaining": 4999,
    "reset": 1372700873
  }
}
```

But only says I need to check this `GET /rate_limit`. But how to use that? Should I do a command like this bellow?

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/users/octocat GET /rate_limit
```

How would be this command?

---

Related questions:

1. [GitHub API limit exceeded: how to increase the rate limit in front-end apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395747/github-api-limit-exceeded-how-to-increase-the-rate-limit-in-front-end-apps)
2. [jspm saying "github rate limit reached" - how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995040/jspm-saying-github-rate-limit-reached-how-to-fix)
3. [Github API: Fetch issues with exceeds rate limit prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655700/github-api-fetch-issues-with-exceeds-rate-limit-prematurely)
4. https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting

Comment: The rate limiting url you provided states each API response contains this information. So you can always update it.

Comment: My response is saying I reached the limit, but shows nothing else: `b'{"error":{"code":403,"status":"Forbidden","message":"{\\"message\\":\\"API rate limit exceeded for myusername.\\",\\"documentation_url\\":\\"https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting\\"}"}}'`, How can I see a complete/full report as the big one on the question? I get that one from the example on the page https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can call this endpoint using

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: token YOUR-OAUTH-TOKEN" -X GET https://api.github.com/rate_limit
```

or similar in Ruby

```rb
    require 'uri' 
    require 'net/http'    
    
    url = URI("https://api.github.com/rate_limit")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)     
    request["Authorization"] = 'token YOUR-OAUTH-TOKEN'

    response = http.request(request) 
    puts response.read_body
```

Comment: How would be an example for this `Basic <insert credentials>`? I need to type my password on plain text? How could I see my unauthenticated rate limit?

Comment: You can use multiple methods https://developer.github.com/v3/#basic-authentication

Comment: If I put the `OAUTH-TOKEN` as in you question it throws the error: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: token, curl: (6) Could not resolve host: OAUTH-TOKEN'`. If I use as `curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" -X GET https://api.github.com/rate_limit`, it does work correctly. Can you update the answer?

Comment: This really worked, also with the new GH API changes made last year.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the **Python** equivalent using `requests`.

Replace `TOKEN` with your token. (I use the Github personal access token found [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens))

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token TOKEN',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/rate_limit', headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```